# OpenCV and Flask camera access issue on deployment - Render

Tags: python, opencv, flask, deployment, render.com

Despite the successful operation of my Flask and OpenCV application locally, I'm encountering camera access issues when deploying it to Render Deployment Platform. Below are the relevant logs and error messages that demonstrate the problem. [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5VyZ.png)
is it because render doesn't allow camera permissions or there is a problem with my python code.

Below is link to my python code
[pose estimation using openCV and mediapipe](https://github.com/jayantghadge/fitsense-major-project/blob/main/exercises/bicep-curls.py)

Comment: You are trying to access the server's camera. However, this one has no camera.

Comment: "Below is link to my python code"—that's not how Stack Overflow works. Please [edit] a [mre] directly into your question.